# change photos in cardboard VR-360 SDK

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am a beginner android programmer and developing a VR app by cardboard SDK and have used a switch-case and button for switch between photos but I know some apps use a central point and "focus on an icon" method to change view of a 360 photo to another photo. for example by 3second looking to that icon call an event to do a function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng6fI.jpg)

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId()==R.id.button1) {
        i = i + 1;
        switch (i) {
            case 2:
                panoImageName = "p1.jpg";
                loadPanoImage();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                panoWidgetView.addFocusables(Imgs[0],1,2);
                break;
            case 3:
               onPause();
                panoImageName = "logo.jpg";
                //loadPanoImage();
               // onResume();
                break;
            case 4:
                panoImageName = "p2.jpg";
                loadPanoImage();
                break;
            case 5:
                panoImageName = "logo.jpg";
                loadPanoImage();
                break;
             }
    }
}
```

do you have any idea for it?

Sample image of a VR app screen:

[image: Sample image of a VR app screen]

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Unity and working to create a VR photo viewer with UI buttons to change the photo. I am able to complete it through multiple resources as described here:

1. I downloaded a unity project from the dropbox link given in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hYXj77CSDks&t=65s
2. The above project can change the photos but by clicking the buttons.
3. To control the next and previous buttons with focus (Gaze) I followed this post:[how to add gaze input timer to trigger an action after gazing for 3secs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475574/how-to-add-gaze-input-timer-to-trigger-an-action-after-gazing-for-3secs)

This worked for me so far.